# Receiving MetaData but Expecting SAML Assertion

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to create a partnership with another organization using SAML for SSO.  We have a URL (let's call it https://ourwebsite.com/SAML/AssertionConsumerService that is expecting a SAML assertion Request via POST but instead we are getting a link to the other organization's Metadata being sent to us in the query string.

I've got a ticket out to the partner org, but they don't seem to understand it without going to their developers and it's taking a while.

We've successfully set up SAML partnerships with other organizations, so I know that we're able to consume the SAML assertions properly.  I've just never heard of this practice (sending a link to the metadata in the query string) and was hoping someone could shed some light on it for me.

Basically we don't need their SAML Metadata to be sent to us because we store that information for all our partners in our database. MY QUESTION IS - Is this a different approach to SAML that I just haven't heard of, or are they just doing it wrong?

Comment: I didn't see a question... But if you're asking if you're right and they're wrong, then the answer is yes. And until they get themselves sorted, you're going to wait.

Comment: @AndyK.-PingIdentity - LOL!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've made the edit, and yes that was my question - so thanks for reading my mind and answering.  I'm going to wait for a few more comments and then will mark you as the answerer - most likely!